# Error when declaring more than one object from the same class "polynomial"

Tags: c++, oop

In this code, it runs fine when I have declared only one object of polynomial class. But as soon as I declare two objects of polynomial class, it does not show any error, but the code does not run. Not even the first line of int main().

I have checked all other functions individually. The only problem is declaration of more than one polynomial class objects!!!

```
    #include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<cstring>
#include<math.h>

using namespace std;

string space_rem(string s)
{
    int i;
    string res;
    for(i=0;i<s.size();i++)
    {
        if(s[i] != ' ')
        res+=s[i];
    }
    return res;
}

string all_in_powers(string s)        //writes every variable in string in its power form x^(i)
{                                     //e.g. abca is written as a^(1)b^(1)c^(1)a^(1)
    string temp = s;

    if(temp.size()==0)
    return temp;

    int i;

    if(temp[temp.size()-1]>='a'&&temp[temp.size()-1]<='z')
    temp+="^(1)";

    string res;

    char x;

    for(i=0;i<temp.size()-3;i++)
    {
        x=temp[i];
        
        if(x>='a' && x<='z' && temp[i+1]!='^')     //if variable not in power form
        {
            res+=x;
            res+="^(1)";                           //writes ab as a^(1)b^(1)
        }

        else
        {
            res+=x;                          //variable in power form so copy as it is
        }
    }

    for(i=temp.size()-3;i<temp.size();i++)
    {
        res+=temp[i];
    }
    return res;
}

class polynomial_term                   //stores everything regarding a polynomial term
{
    public:
        int powers[26]={0};              //power of each variable from a to z
        string pol;                      //string representation of term without coefficient
        int coeff;                       //coefficient of term
        char sign; 
        int pow_sum;                      //positive or negative 
    
    public:
        void full_term(string s);            //inputs string form and puts all the data of the term in this class's object
        void string_construct();             //makes the string representation pol from the powers array
        void pol_pow(string s);              //gathers data of total power of each variable from input string
        void display();                       //displays the complete polynomial term
        polynomial_term operator * (polynomial_term);    //to multiply two terms   
        bool operator < (polynomial_term); 
        bool operator > (polynomial_term);      
        bool operator == (polynomial_term);  
        void display_pow();
        polynomial_term operator + (polynomial_term);
        void copy_frm(polynomial_term);

};

void polynomial_term::copy_frm(polynomial_term B)
{
    for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
    {
        powers[i]=B.powers[i];
    }
    coeff=B.coeff;
    pol=B.pol;
    sign=B.sign;
    pow_sum=B.pow_sum;

}

void polynomial_term:: display_pow()
{
    for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
    {
        cout<<powers[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

void polynomial_term::display()                                    
{
    /*if(coeff==0)
    {
        cout<<"0\n";
    }*/

    if(coeff==1)
    {   
        if(pol.size()!=0)
        cout<<pol<<endl;

        else
        {
            cout<<1<<endl;               //only coefficient printed as pol is empty
        }
        
    }        

    else
    {
        if(coeff!=-1)
        cout<<coeff<<pol<<endl;

        else
        cout<<"-"<<pol<<endl;
        
    }
    

}

void polynomial_term::string_construct()              //generates pol member of polynomial term class using powers array
{
    pol.clear();

    /*if(coeff!=1)
    {
        pol+=to_string(coeff);
    }*/



    for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
    {
        if(powers[i]!=0)
        {
            pol+=(char)(i+'a');

            if(powers[i]!=1)
            {
                pol+="^(";
                pol+=to_string((powers[i]));
                pol+=')';
            }
        }
    }
}

void polynomial_term::pol_pow(string s)               //
{
    char x;

    if(s.size()==0)
    return;

    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
    {
        x=s[i];

        if(x>='a'&&x<='z')
        {
            string tmp;
            int pow;

            for(int j=i+3;s[j]!=')';j++)           //gathers power of variable in tmp string
            {
                tmp+=s[j];
            }

            pow=stoi(tmp);
            powers[x-'a']+=pow;
        }
    }

    pow_sum=0;

    for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
    {
        pow_sum+=powers[i];
    }
}

void polynomial_term::full_term(string s)        //inputs raw string and organises its data in the polynomial_term class object
{
    sign='+';          //default sign

    coeff=1;                    //default coefficient     

    for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
    {
        powers[i]=0;
    }       

    pol.clear();

    pow_sum=0;

    int i=0;

    if(s[0]=='-')
    {
        sign='-';
        i++;
    }

   string tmp;

    while(i<s.size() && s[i]>='0' && s[i]<='9')          //tmp collects the coefficient part
    {
        tmp+=s[i];
        i++;
    }

    if(tmp.size()>0)coeff=stoi(tmp);

    if(sign=='-')                     
    coeff*=-1;

    tmp="";

    if(1)
    {
        for(int j=i;j<s.length();j++)
        {
            tmp+=s[j];
        }

    }

    s=tmp;

    s=all_in_powers(s);
    pol_pow(s);
    string_construct();
}

polynomial_term  polynomial_term::operator * (polynomial_term B)   //returns multiplication of terms
{
    polynomial_term res;

    res.coeff=coeff*B.coeff;

    if(res.coeff<0)
    res.sign='-';

    string temp=pol+B.pol;

    temp=all_in_powers(temp);
    res.pol_pow(temp);
    res.string_construct();

    return res;

}

bool polynomial_term::operator < (polynomial_term B)                                      //lexicographic order comparison
{
   // bool flag=0;

   /*if(pow_sum==B.pow_sum)
   {
       for(int i=0; i<26; i++)
       {
            if(powers[i]>B.powers[i])
            {
                //if(B.powers[i]==0)
                //return false;

                return false;
            }

            else if(powers[i]<B.powers[i])
            {    
                return true;                 
            }

        }

   }*/

    for(int i=0; i<26; i++)
    {
        if(powers[i]>B.powers[i])
        {
            //if(B.powers[i]==0)
            //return false;

            return true;
        }

        else if(powers[i]<B.powers[i])
        {    
            return false;                 
        }

    }

    return false;
}

bool polynomial_term::operator > (polynomial_term B)                                      //lexicographic order comparison
{
    for(int i=0; i<26; i++)
    {
        if(powers[i]>B.powers[i])
        return false;

        else
        {
            if(powers[i]<B.powers[i])
            return true;

            else
            continue;
            
        }

    }

    return false;
}

bool polynomial_term::operator == (polynomial_term B)
{

    for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
    {
        if(powers[i] != B.powers[i])
        return false;
    }

    return true;

}

polynomial_term  polynomial_term::operator + (polynomial_term B)            //return addition of polynomial_terms
{
    polynomial_term C;

    if(pol!=B.pol)
    {
        cout<<"Error: Adding two non_compatible polynomial terms!!\n";
    }

    C.coeff = coeff+B.coeff;

    if(C.coeff<0)
    C.sign='-';

    else 
    C.sign='+';

    C.pol=pol;
    //cout<<"*\n";
    C.pol_pow(all_in_powers(pol));
    //cout<<"**\n";
    C.string_construct();
    //cout<<"*\n";

    return C;

}

class polynomial
{
    public:
        polynomial_term terms[10000];
        int term_count;
        string expression;
    
    public:
        void expression_generate();

        polynomial(): term_count(0),expression("0")
        {
            polynomial_term X;
            X.full_term("0");

            for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
            {
                terms[i].copy_frm(X);
            }
        }

        polynomial(string s)                                                      //constructor segregates terms and stores them in terms array
        {
            //cout<<"uo\n";

            polynomial_term X;
            X.full_term("0");

            for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
            {
                terms[i].copy_frm(X);
            }

            s=all_in_powers(s);

            polynomial_term tmp;
            string temp="";
            int i;

            for(i=0;!(i!=0 && s[i]=='+'|| s[i]=='-') && i<s.size();i++)         //put first term in the array
            {
                temp+=s[i];
            }

            cout<<"***"<<i<<endl;

            tmp.full_term(temp);
            terms[0]=tmp;
            temp="";
            term_count=1;

            while(i<s.size())
            {
                if(s[i]=='+' )
                {
                    temp="";
                    i++;

                    while(s[i]!='+' && s[i]!='-' && i<s.size())
                    {
                        temp+=s[i];
                        i++;
                    }

                    tmp.full_term(temp);
                    terms[term_count]=tmp;
                    term_count++;
                }

                else if(s[i]=='-')
                {
                    temp="-";
                    i++;

                    while(s[i]!='+' && s[i]!='-' && i<s.size())
                    {
                        temp+=s[i];
                        i++;
                    }

                    tmp.full_term(temp);
                    terms[term_count]=tmp;
                    term_count++;

                }
            }
            expression_generate();
        }

        void lexicosort();
        void powersort();
        void display_terms();
        //void expression_generate();
        void display();
        bool found(polynomial_term);
};

void polynomial::display_terms()
{
    for(int i =0;i<term_count;i++)
    {
        terms[i].display();
    }
}

void polynomial::display()
{
    cout<<expression<<endl;
}

void polynomial::powersort()
{
    polynomial_term least;
    int least_index,i,j;

    for(i=0;i<term_count;i++)
    {
        least = terms[i];
        least_index = i;


        for(j=i;j<term_count;j++)
        {
            if(terms[j].pow_sum<least.pow_sum)
            {
           
                least=terms[j];
                least_index=j;
            }

        }

        polynomial_term temp = terms[i];
        terms[i] = terms[least_index];
        terms[least_index] = temp;

    }


}

void polynomial::lexicosort()
{
    polynomial_term least;
    int least_index,i,j;

    for(i=0;i<term_count;i++)
    {
        least = terms[i];
        least_index = i;

        for(j=i;j<term_count;j++)
        {
            if(terms[j]<least)
            {
  
                least=terms[j];
                least_index=j;
            }

        }

        polynomial_term temp = terms[i];
        terms[i] = terms[least_index];
        terms[least_index] = temp;

    }


}

void polynomial::expression_generate()
{
   // cout<<"**\n";
    expression.clear();

    expression="";

    if(term_count==0)
    {
        //cout<<"*\n";
        expression="0";
        return;
    }


    for(int i=0;i<term_count;i++)
    {
        //cout<<"lolo\n";
        if(terms[i].coeff==0)
        {
            if(i==1)
            {
                expression="0";
                return;
            }

            else
            {
                continue;
            }
            

        }

        if((terms[i].coeff)!=1 && (terms[i].coeff)!=-1)
        {
            if(i!=0)
            expression += terms[i].sign;

            expression += to_string(terms[i].coeff);
        }

        else
        {
            if(i!=0)
            expression += terms[i].sign;
        }
           
        expression += terms[i].pol;
    }
}

bool polynomial::found(polynomial_term X)
{
    for(int i=0;i<term_count;i++)
    {
        if(X==terms[i])
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

/*polynomial comp(polynomial A)                    //compresses by grouping similar terms (terms that can be added)
{
    A.lexicosort();
     A.expression_generate();
    A.powersort();
    A.expression_generate();

    polynomial_term tmp;
    tmp.copy_frm(A.terms[0]);
    polynomial res;

    for(int i=1;i<A.term_count;i++)
    {
        if(!(A.terms[i]==tmp))
        {
            res.terms[res.term_count].copy_frm(tmp);
            res.term_count++;
            tmp.copy_frm(A.terms[i]);
        }

        else
        {
            polynomial_term X=tmp+A.terms[i];
            tmp.copy_frm(X);         
        }
        

    }

    res.expression_generate();

    return res;

}*/


int main()
{
   cout<<"*\n";
    polynomial A("a");
   // polynomial B;
    cout<<"*\n";
    polynomial B("a+b+b+a");
    A.display();
    cout<<"*\n";

   


    /* A.lexicosort();
     A.expression_generate();
    A.powersort();
    A.expression_generate();

     cout<<"*\n";

    A.display_terms();
    cout<<"*\n";*/

    //res.expression_generate();

    //res.display();
}
```

Comment: Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `polynomial_term terms[10000];` is pretty big and might not fit on the stack. You might want to dynamically allocate this sucker. Wouldn't be surprised if this is the problem you've run into.

Comment: [Quick test](https://ideone.com/2uUobA) shows a single `polynomial` weighs in at about a megabyte-and-a-half. Two of them is likely exhausting the program's Automatic storage causing a... wait for it... Stack Overflow.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks man/woman!!!!   THAT was the ONLY problem in ALL of that code!!!!  You ARE GAWWDD!!!!